# After click stop loop button, can't Start again

Tags: c#

I use backgroundworker as suggested in the previous statement and it works. but I have a new problem, that is after pressing the Stop button, the thread can't start again, must click 2 times

```
private bool _stopLoop;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BW_PING.RunWorkerAsync();
    this.btPing.Enabled = false;
    _stopLoop = false;
}

private void Ping(bool Type)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000 && !_stopLoop; ++i)
    {
        using (Ping p = new Ping())
        {
            Ping pingClass = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = pingClass.Send(tbUrl.Text);
            lbPing.Text = ("Ping - " + pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " Ms");
        }
    }
}

private void btStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stopLoop = true;
    this.btPing.Enabled = true;
    lbPing.Text = ("Ping Stoped");
}

private void BW_PING_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    Ping(true);
}
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: _stopLoop = false; put this line beginning of the button1_Click function

Comment: `as suggested in the previous Statement, but I have a new problem` - what are you talking about?

Comment: Your code seems incomplete… - you are never stoping your backgroundworker but on each button click you are trying to run it again - for some reason you are casting the `sender` in `BW_PING_DoWork` but never use that - are we playing a puzzle and we are supposed to fill in the blanks? or did I miss something?

Comment: does it mean that I just have to stop the backgrounworker?

Comment: sorry for bad english :(

Comment: The question only contains part of the problem. Try giving a [mcve]. Unrelated tip: you don't need the brackets around either of the values that you are assigning to the `Text` property.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker class has support for cancellation baked into it. So why are you building your own cancellation mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things wrong with this code, for example why does the `Ping(bool Type)` Method require a parameter even thought it's not used within the Method?

The simplest solution would be, as Hameed Syed pointed out in the comments, put `_stopLoop = false;` at the start of `button1_Click` Method. But it might be worth more redoing the entire thing